# Linux NASM - Drain Terminal Input Without Prompt

Tags: linux, assembly, terminal, nasm

I want to drain terminal input before prompting the user, or otherwise to close the terminal input until I want to prompt the user for input.

I am writing a program that uses `sys_read` to prompt the user for input through the terminal. If a user types characters before being prompted, those characters get included in the input. I can easily drain every unread character after the prompt using `sys_read` again, but it relies on a return character being at the end of the stream of input to prevent prompting the user more than once (I am assuming the user ends every prompt with the return key). I can't rely on the presence of a return character before the prompt, so I can't drain the input the same way.

I have also tried closing stdin with `sys_close`, but I can't figure out how to open terminal input again, so the program is left frozen when a prompt comes up. Even if I could open the terminal input again, I'm not sure whether or not characters typed while it's closed still get saved for the next time it's read, which would render this approach completely useless.

If there is some sort of obscure termios flag that could disable user input, that would also be an excellent solution.

Here's a program, for example:

```
   global _start

_start:
   
   mov edx,ldot
   mov ecx,mdot
   mov ebx,1
   mov eax,4    ; sys_write
   int 0x80
   
   mov dword[sleep_sec],1
   mov dword[sleep_usec],0
   mov ecx,0
   mov ebx,sleep
   mov eax,162  ; sys_nanosleep
   int 0x80
   
   mov edx,ldesire
   mov ecx,mdesire
   mov ebx,1
   mov eax,4    ; sys_write
   int 0x80
   
   call input   ;  here's the call...
   
   mov edx,lreceive
   mov ecx,mreceive
   mov ebx,1
   mov eax,4    ; sys_write
   int 0x80
   
   mov dword[sleep_sec],1
   mov dword[sleep_usec],0
   mov ecx,0
   mov ebx,sleep
   mov eax,162  ; sys_nanosleep
   int 0x80
   
   mov edx,99
   mov ecx,inputed
   mov ebx,1
   mov eax,4    ; sys_write
   int 0x80
   
   mov eax,1    ; sys_exit
   int 0x80     ; the end!



input:          ;   here is all that I am concerned about
   mov edx,99
   mov ecx,inputed
   mov ebx,0    ; stdin
   mov eax,3    ; sys_read
   int 0x80
   
   cmp eax,99   ; check for valid input
   jl inputdone
   cmp byte[inputed+98],0xa
   je inputdone
   
   inputclear:  ; drain
      mov eax,3
      int 0x80
      cmp eax,99
      jl inputerror
      cmp byte[inputed+98],0xa
      je inputerror
      jmp inputclear
   
   inputerror:
      mov eax,-1
      ret
   inputdone:
      mov eax,1
      ret



section .bss   
inputed resb 99

section .data

sleep:
   sleep_sec  dd 0
   sleep_usec dd 0

mdot db '...',0xA
ldot equ $ - mdot

mdesire db 'tell me your truest desire:'
ldesire equ $ - mdesire

mreceive db 'you shall receive... '
lreceive equ $ - mreceive
```

A user who does things when they are told will find no trouble:

```
...
tell me your truest desire:money
you shall receive... money
```

But a user who likes to press buttons as they please will struggle:

```
...
a gtell me your truest desire:love
you shall receive... a glove
```

And the program won't wait for anyone who makes a mess with the return key:

```
...
who
tell me your truest desire:you shall receive... who
```

Comment: If you don't mess with terminal settings input is going to be line buffered, you won't get any characters read until the user presses enter. So you can rely on that.

Comment: I don't see how that helps with characters sneaking in from *before* the prompt. I can drain characters trailing at the end just fine.

Comment: You drain everything before you print the prompt? Heck, you don't even need to worry about end of line, just read until you get 0 bytes back. Or am I misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: I don't know how to drain before the prompt without prompting the user during the drain. I use sys_read to drain and that relies a return character existing in the input to not prompt the user again -- perfect for draining after a prompt, not so much before a prompt when I don't know whether or not a return character exists in the input. So here when I do give the prompt, I have no way of distinguishing characters typed before the prompt and those typed during the prompt.

Comment: Due to line buffering you don't even get the characters entered before or during the prompt until enter is pressed. You need to switch line buffering off. You can then also turn echo off and ignore anything entered before the prompt. I believe you have already been pointed at code how to do that.

Comment: Waiting for the return key to be pressed to get characters is fine, it's what I want. My only concern is distinguishing between characters typed during and before the prompt.
What exactly is line buffering? Is it related to canonical mode and is it a flag I can set? (A list of all the termios flags with their bitwise positions would be great, I haven't been able to find one)
And yes, I am familiar with setting the echo flag in the termios thanks to being pointed towards other questions related to the subject.

Comment: Also, speaking of termios, is there a flag that can drain the input buffer by setting it or something similar (TCSETSW is something I see coming up often)? I currently only know how to drain the input by using sys_read and another means of doing so may solve my problem.

Comment: I think you want tcflush(TCIFLUSH) (or in asm, the underlying ioctl) to discard pending unread input.  This even clears the contents of the line-edit buffer (typed but not pressed return on yet) with the TTY in canonical mode.  See `termios(3)` and `ioctl_tt(2)`.  (ping @Jester: this does things you can't do easily / at all with just reads, except maybe by making stdin non-blocking so you can read until it drains, but even then you can't clear the line-edit buffer.)

Comment: (... except by making the TTY raw so you could drain everything, but that's really cumbersome.)

Comment: @Octopus: FYI: you can open the controlling TTY for your process as `/dev/tty`.  At least I think that's what that file is, and do sometimes use `foo | tee /dev/tty | bar` to inspect part of a shell pipeline so I know it works for that.  As long as you still have some FD open on the terminal (like stdout or stderr), opening /dev/tty should work.  I only have a rough understanding of what "controlling TTY" means and how that works.  But anyway, I think typed characters would still be there waiting to be read on the TTY after opening a new FD onto it, like `dup(0)` to copy an existing fd.

Comment: TCIFLUSH seems to be what I'm looking for. I'm guessing ```termios(3)``` and ```ioctl_tt(2)``` are manual pages but I can't find any documentation that provides the ioctl numbers.